Throw an thisNullReferenceException when I perform a static code scan of java code
This is my first time to use the software. When I selected the java project to perform the scan, the program did not respond. Here is the log information.
enter image description here
json
06/05/2024 13:32:00,366 [5] INFO  Available memory: 3664 Used memory: 431 Elapsed Time: 00:00:25.6057167 [Unspecified] - End loading sources from project original location to local destination location : 'C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Checkmarx\Checkmarx SAST\CxAuditSrc\base-user-server'  
06/05/2024 13:32:00,386 [5] INFO  Available memory: 3664 Used memory: 431 Elapsed Time: 00:00:25.6263276 [Unspecified] - ProjectLoadingThread -- Finish  
06/05/2024 13:32:00,692 [MainThread_CxAudit] INFO  Available memory: 3664 Used memory: 431 Elapsed Time: 00:00:25.9318138 [Unspecified] - ProjectLoading_Shown -- Exception  
06/05/2024 13:32:00,693 [MainThread_CxAudit] INFO  Available memory: 3664 Used memory: 431 Elapsed Time: 00:00:25.9324926 [Unspecified] - ProjectLoading_Shown: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: InvalidArgument=“-1”的值对于“index”无效。
参数名: index
   在 System.Windows.Forms.ListView.ListViewItemCollection.get_Item(Int32 index)
   在 CxAudit.ProjectLoading.ProjectLoading_Shown(Object sender, EventArgs e)  
06/05/2024 13:32:00,693 [MainThread_CxAudit] INFO  Available memory: 3664 Used memory: 431 Elapsed Time: 00:00:25.9325402 [Unspecified] - ProjectLoading_Shown -- Finish  
06/05/2024 13:32:00,699 [MainThread_CxAudit] INFO  Available memory: 3664 Used memory: 431 Elapsed Time: 00:00:25.9393617 [Unspecified] - LoadingProjectCancellation: System.NullReferenceException: 未将对象引用设置到对象的实例。
   在 CxAudit.FormsMetadata.AuditForm.AuditFormMetadata.LoadingProjectCancellation()  
06/05/2024 13:32:00,700 [MainThread_CxAudit] INFO  Available memory: 3664 Used memory: 431 Elapsed Time: 00:00:25.9394695 [Unspecified] - Cancel Loading Project  
06/05/2024 13:32:00,700 [MainThread_CxAudit] INFO  Available memory: 3664 Used memory: 431 Elapsed Time: 00:00:25.9397075 [Unspecified] - Clear: System.NullReferenceException: 未将对象引用设置到对象的实例。
   在 CxAudit.CxAuditProject.Clear()  


version info:
Product version: 9.5.0.0-390131
Available memory: 3772Mb
Used memory: 381Mb
OS: Microsoft Windows NT 10.0.19045.0
Product: Checkmarx SAST Engine
-   Main Version: 9.5.0.100
-   Hotfix Version: 0
-   Path: F:\CxSAST\Checkmarx\Checkmarx Engine Service\
Product: Checkmarx SAST Audit
-   Main Version: 9.5.0.100
-   Hotfix Version: 0
-   Path: F:\CxSAST\Checkmarx\Checkmarx Audit\
Current Product dll's version list:
___________________________________
Assembly name:                 File version:
ASP.dll                        9.5.0.0-390131
CSharp.dll                     9.5.0.0-390131
DataCollections.dll            9.5.0.0-390131
EngineFacade.dll               9.5.0.0-390131
Flowgraphs.dll                 9.5.0.0-390131
Plugin.dll                     9.5.0.0-390131
Query.dll                      9.5.0.0-390131
CxWrm.dll                      9.5.0.0-390131
CxSyntaxEdit.dll               9.5.0.0-390131
QWhale.Common.dll              2.3.0.0
QWhale.Editor.dll              2.3.0.0
QWhale.Syntax.dll              2.3.0.0
QWhale.Syntax.Parsers.dll      2.3.0.0

I have tried to scan for another java project and will report the same error.
